# I can't seem to adjust visual of my 3d scatter plot to how I want it (size/position)

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-express

I know with plotly express, I am able to zoom in and out of the figure...however when I first open it, it is not automatically set to fit within the margins of the display. So, part of the graph gets cut off, as seen below:

[plot cut off](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ug9D.png)

How can I adjust this in the script? Furthermore, I want to make the graph a cube shape, but when I set the range and tick interval of say, for example the x axis (labelled GSI), i get this instead of it cubing out...

[adjusted x-axis plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7hUcS.png)

Instead, I would like it to look more like this one that I plotted using matplotlib

[goal plot visual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VYIdb.jpg)

This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.io as pio
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go
pio.renderers.default = "browser"

df = pd.read_excel('/Users/alissanicolet./Desktop/QGIS_Thesis/pythongraphexcel.xlsx')
print(df)
r_x=[0,1]
r_y=[0,1]
r_z=[0.9,2]

fig = px.scatter_3d(
    data_frame=df,
    x='GSI',
    y='OSR',
    z='FSI',
    range_x=(r_x),
    range_y=(r_y),
    range_z=(r_z),
    color="Sample",
    color_discrete_sequence=['magenta','green','blue'],
   #template='plotly_dark',
    template='seaborn',
    title='Spacematrix of Sample Areas',
    hover_name='Sample',
    height=700,
    
)

fig.update_scenes(yaxis_autorange="reversed")
fig.update_scenes(xaxis_dtick=0.1)
fig.update_scenes(yaxis_dtick=0.1)
#fig.update_scenes(zaxis_dtick=0.2)


# Use for animation rotation at the end
x_eye = -1.25
y_eye = 2
z_eye = 0.5


# Use for animation rotation
fig.update_layout(scene_camera_eye=dict(x=x_eye, y=y_eye, z=z_eye),
                   updatemenus=[dict(type='buttons',
                                     showactive=False,
                                     y=1,
                                     x=0.8,
                                     xanchor='left',
                                     yanchor='bottom',
                                     pad=dict(t=45, r=10),
                                     buttons=[dict(label='Play',
                                                   method='animate',
                                                   args=[None, dict(frame=dict(duration=200, redraw=True),
                                                                    transition=dict(duration=0),
                                                                    fromcurrent=True,
                                                                    mode='immediate'
                                                                    )]
                                                   )
                                              ]
                                     )
                                ]
                   )


def rotate_z(x, y, z, theta):
     w = x + 1j * y
     return np.real(np.exp(1j * theta) * w), np.imag(np.exp(1j * theta) * w), z


frames = []

for t in np.arange(0, 6.26, 0.1):
     xe, ye, ze = rotate_z(x_eye, y_eye, z_eye, -t)
     frames.append(go.Frame(layout=dict(scene_camera_eye=dict(x=xe, y=ye, z=ze))))
fig.frames = frames


#fig.write_html("spacematrix_thompson.html")


pio.show(fig)
```